# Are there examples of male characters dressing as women in Elizabethan/Jacobean literature?

Tags: english-renaissance-theater

In Tudor/Stuart literature and drama there are a lot of female characters dressing as men. And, of course, the male *actors* dress as female characters. But are there any plays or novels from the era where male characters cross-dress as women?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a monograph on male-to-female cross-dressing in this period:

> Perhaps the most famous instance of a man dressed as a woman in early modern literature is the scene in William Shakespeare’s [*The Merry Wives of Windsor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Merry_Wives_of_Windsor) in which the wives dress Falstaff in the gown, hat, and muffler of the aunt of Mistress Ford’s maid, the old witch of Brainford. […] Beyond Falstaff, there are more than thirty other instances in English texts from the late sixteenth and early seventeenth centuries in which fictional male characters dress as and pass for women for sustained periods of time.
>
> <sub>Simone Chess (2016). [*Male-to-Female Crossdressing in Early Modern English Literature*, p. 1](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Male_to_Female_Crossdressing_in_Early_Mo/Z2z7CwAAQBAJ). London: Routledge.</sub>

Other instances mentioned by Chess include:

- Pyrocles in Philip Sidney’s [*Arcadia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Countess_of_Pembroke%27s_Arcadia) (1593).
- Follywit in Thomas Middleton’s [*A Mad World, My Masters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mad_World%2C_My_Masters) (1605).
- Epicœne in Ben Jonson’s [*Epicœne, or the Silent Woman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic%C5%93ne%2C_or_The_Silent_Woman) (1609).
- The Prince in Margaret Cavendish’s [*The Convent of Pleasure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Convent_of_Pleasure) (1688).